# generate gpg public and private keys without any interaction

Tags: centos, gnupg

I would like to know how to generate gpg public and private keys without any human interaction

i need instructions to build a bash to do suck work ,something like:

```
name=$1
email=$2
pubkeypath=$3
gpg  --gen-key --name $name --email $email .........
gpg --export -a $name > $pubkeypath
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a feature for unattendet operation; according to the [online documentation](http://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg-devel/OpenPGP-Key-Management.html#OpenPGP-Key-Management), this feature is still experimental, i.e. the interface might break during an update.
This interface allows you to pipe a sequence of commands to gpg's stdin, which must be called with the parameters `--gen-key` and `--batch`. A description of the commands possible is found [on this webpage](http://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg-devel/Unattended-GPG-key-generation.html).