# How to call CMD to create GnuPG-Keypair from Java

Tags: java, console, runtime, processbuilder, gnupg

I'm trying to execute a gpg-command in Java to create a new Keypair, but I'm not getting an answer from the console. My code works well if I try to execute a gpg-command for the version `gpg --version` or to retrieve the keylist with `gpg --list-key`.

I'm using code from another [Stackoverflow-Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4367090/calling-gnupg-in-java-via-a-runtime-process-to-encrypt-and-decrypt-files-decry):

```
public void getKeyList(){
    try {

        Process gpgProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("gpg --gen-key");

        BufferedReader gpgOutput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(gpgProcess.getInputStream()));
        BufferedWriter gpgInput = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(gpgProcess.getOutputStream()));
        BufferedReader gpgErrorOutput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(gpgProcess.getErrorStream()));

        boolean executing = true;

        while(executing){
              try {
                int exitValue = gpgProcess.exitValue();

                if (gpgErrorOutput.ready()){
                    String error = getStreamText(gpgErrorOutput);
                    System.err.println(error);
                }else if (gpgOutput.ready()){
                    System.out.println(getStreamText(gpgOutput));

                }
            } catch (Exception e){
              //The process is not yet ready to exit.  Take a break and try again.
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                    System.err.println("This thread has insomnia: " + e1.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }


    } catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

private String getStreamText(BufferedReader reader) throws IOException{
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    try{
        while(reader.ready()){
            result.append(reader.readLine());
            if(reader.ready()){
                result.append("\n");
            }
        }
    }catch(IOException ioe){
        System.err.println("Error while reading the stream: " + ioe.getMessage());
        throw ioe;
    }
    return result.toString();
}
```

I've also tried `ProcessBuilder` instead of `Runtime`, but that's not the solution.
Do you have any idea on how to solve this problem, or is it totally impossible to interact with the console during the key-generation process?

Comment: If the usage of bouncycastle is no option, this question is very simlar to (or even a duplicate of) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21605909/generate-gpg-public-and-private-keys-without-any-interaction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gpg --genkey` is an interactive call, which waits for input, which you never provide. Two possible solutions:

1. Use bouncycastle instead, which is a native Java library for OpenPGP.
2. As implementing an interactive GnuPG session will be rather complicated and error-prone, you might better use the "experimental feature" for batch key generation. From `man gpg`:

   ```
   --gen-key
         Generate a new key pair. This command is normally only used
         interactively.

         There is an experimental feature which allows you to create
         keys  in  batch  mode.  See  the  file `doc/DETAILS' in the
         source distribution on how to use this.
   ```

   The file [`doc/DETAILS` is also available online](http://git.gnupg.org/cgi-bin/gitweb.cgi?p=gnupg.git;a=blob;f=doc/DETAILS;h=fe55ae16ab4e26d8356dc574c9e8bc935e71aef1;hb=refs/heads/STABLE-BRANCH-1-4). The section you want to look up is called "Unattended key generation". It's rather lengthy, so I didn't quote it here, but this is the example from the document on how to do it:

   ```
   $ cat >foo <<EOF
        %echo Generating a basic OpenPGP key
        Key-Type: DSA
        Key-Length: 1024
        Subkey-Type: ELG-E
        Subkey-Length: 1024
        Name-Real: Joe Tester
        Name-Comment: with stupid passphrase
        Name-Email: joe@foo.bar
        Expire-Date: 0
        Passphrase: abc
        %pubring foo.pub
        %secring foo.sec
        # Do a commit here, so that we can later print "done" :-)
        %commit
        %echo done
   EOF
   $ gpg --batch --gen-key foo
   ```

Comment: Thank you very much! Although I also would prefer to use BouncyCastle, it is no option in this project. I will try the experimental feature instead. Again: Thank you :)